# Teniendo un combobox mostrando los datos de una COLUMNA de una DB, ¿Como puedo llenar inputs con los demas valores?

Tags: php, ajax, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla llamada "sitios" (ejemplo de phpmyadmin):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un formulario donde tengo un select el cual ya tengo echa la consulta a la tabla "sitios" para que muestre solo los datos de la columna "Sitio" de esta misma tabla, lo que busco es que en otros inputs se coloque el valor ("Referencia", "Domicilio", "Telefono", "Ciudad") respectivo al "Sitio" seleccionado en el select.

Aquí esta el código, desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse la molestia de leer mi problema, saludos!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 *
 * @author Zarate
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $serv = "localhost";
        $dataB = "cdv1";
        
        $mysqli = new mysqli($serv, $user, $pass, $dataB);
        
        ?>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Solicita tu Cuenta</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/solicitud.css">-->
<!--        <script src="JS/soloLetras.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/soloLetrasv2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/keyCURP.js"></script>
        <script src="js/soloNumeros.js"></script>
        <script src="js/letraCapital.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="formSoli" action="Confirmacion.php" class="formSolicitud" method="POST">
            <button type="button" onclick="location='/CuentasDominio/login/index.php'" class="btnAdmin">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
            </button>
            <h1 class="formTitulo">Solicitud</h1>
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
<!--            onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);" required onkeypress="return soloLetras(event);"-->
            
<!--            Se retiro ya que es necesario que el nombre y apellidos sea en minusculas, solo la primer letra mayuscula -> onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"-->
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Paterno</label>
            <input type="text" name="apeP" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Apellido Materno</label>
            <input type="text" name="apeM" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" title="Desactivar Bloq Mayus" maxlength="40" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onkeypress="return letraCapital(event,this);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Titulo</label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ejemplo: Ingeniero en ..." title="Campo Opcional" maxlength="80" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloLetrasv2(event);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Puesto</label>
            <input type="text" name="puesto" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Departamento</label>
            <input type="text" name="depa" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false">
            <!--            sitio-->
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Sitio</label>
            <select name="sitio" id="sitio" class="formSelect" title="Seleccione el sitio correspondiente" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=6;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">                
                <?php
                
                $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");
                while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    echo '<option>'.$valores[Sitio].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            
            
            <!--            input hidden-->
            <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" value="">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="dom" id="dom" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="tel" id="tel" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="">
            
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
            
            <label for="" class="formLabel">CURP</label>
            <input type="text" name="curp" class="formInput" onselectstart="return false" autocomplete="off" size="18" maxlength="18" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return keyCURP(event);" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">   
            <label for="" class="formLabel">N°Seguro Social</label>
            <input type="text" name="numSS" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
            <label for="" class="formLabel">Matricula</label>
            <input type="text" name="matri" class="formInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="9" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" required onKeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
            
            <input type="submit" src="Confirmacion.php" id="btnSoli" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Enviar Datos">
        </form>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es mejor si usa `AJAX` para lo que quiere lograr.

Comment: tendras un ejemplo amigo? no e usado ajax mas si me han dicho que lo utilice

Comment: Es un ejercicio largo como para un ejemplo(de echo su pregunta es más una explicación). pero documentece sobre `AJAX` y combinelo con `JQUERY` es mucho mejor tanto para el cliente como para el desarrollado.

Answer (score 0):

Yo metería un paso más y utilizaría el foreach que suele dar mejor resultado:

```
<?php
     $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");

     $valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

     foreach ($valores as $valor) { ?>

           <option><?php echo $valor["Sitio"] ?></option>

    <?php }
?>
```

Comment: pero como podria hacer que tomen los otros valores de la tabla cuando seleccione un "sitio" en especifico

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que dar un valor a los option y utilizar una función .change() :

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  //Opción 1: Hacer consulta ajax con el valor del option
  //Opción 2: Guardar la consulta php en un script y recuperar los valores de ahí
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en php, pero si seria una buena idea usar un foreach

```
 <select name="sitio" id="sitio" class="formSelect" title="Seleccione el sitio correspondiente" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=6;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">                
            <?php
            
            $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM Sitios");
            $valores = mysqli_fecth_array($query);

            foreach ($valores as $valor) { ?>

             <option><?php echo $valor["Sitio"] ?></option>

           <?php }

            ?>
        </select>
```